# how to read a 2D array from a txt file ? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

So that is my crappy code

```
    class begin
    {
        public static string[] Reader()
        {
            string[] theMap = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\Console Slayer\Map\map.txt");
            string[] Map = theMap.Clone() as string[];
            return Map;
        }
        public static void Printer()
        {
            foreach (string line in Reader())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Reader();
            Printer();
        }
    }
```

I want to make the Map string into an 2D array for a feature use.
I am new to programing and i know my code is bad.

Comment: Great! What is your question? Seriously, there isn't *remotely* enough information for us to help you here.

Comment: how to make the Map array into an 2d array

Comment: Can you provide more information for what you're trying to accomplish?  What does your data look like, why do you need a 2D array, and what should it's structure look like?

Comment: mapping an array into a 2D array depends entirely on how *you* want it to be structured/mapped. There is no "right" answer, especially without more information.

Comment: i need just one 2d array that i can access in the feature

Comment: whatever array it is. i just need one

Comment: You aren't helping yourself.  We can't guess what you need.

Comment: So are you asking how to *declare* a 2D array? I still don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: even i dont know what i need

Comment: maybe you should back up and figure that out first

Comment: A string *already is* an array of characters, [you can access the character at a given index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  So a 1d array of strings is a 2d array of chars.

Comment: i know how to declare 2d array but i dont know how to make it when its reading from txt

Comment: You need to specify the file format of your "map.txt" file.

Comment: @nightxx come on.  Imagine our perspective.  We don't know what `map.txt` contains.  There's no distinct way to read from a text file into a 2D array.  I'm not sure you know what a 2D array is.  You have to provide some context

Comment: Ok its like a simple text in the console which i am going to use for a map and to move my character i need to access it with y and x. its so simple.And also to print it with 2 for loops noting special.

Comment: I'm throwing in the towel

Comment: post a sample of your text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

Yes, it is a VB component, but it works. No need to reinvent the wheel. Sample usage:

```
  OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
        od.Filter = "Tab delimited file (*.txt)|*.txt";
        if (od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            using (var reader = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(od.FileName))
            {
                reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
                reader.Delimiters = new string[] { "\t" }; // the delimeter of the lines in your file


                reader.ReadLine(); // skip header if needed, ignore titles
                while (!reader.EndOfData)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var currentRow = reader.ReadFields(); // string array
                       // Include code here to handle the row.
                    }

                    catch (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException vex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Line " + vex.Message + " is invalid. Skipping");
                    }
               }
         }
      }
```

Comment: There's no closing brace for your try block.